# Checking to see how many divs there are in if statement

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to check to see how many divs I have in the DOM. when I create a variable that displays there length, it gives me undefined in the console. However, when I alert the variable it returns the value of "8".

I'm trying to write an if statement to see how many divs there are and display it's output. However, my if statement isn't returning the true block. Instead, it's going to else instead.

Here is what I've tried.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">div1</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">div2</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">div3</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">div4</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">div5</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">div6</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">div7</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">div8</div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
var cols = $('.col-lg-2').length;
if(cols.length == 8) {
    alert("there are 8 divs");
}
else {
    alert("there isn't 8 divs");
}
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong but I want the if statement not to go to the else block.

Comment: if (cols === 8). You already have length in the first line

Comment: `cols` already is the length. And `(8).length` will return `undefined` which is false. Hence you hit your `else` block.

Comment: How come my if statement is going to the else block instead then? isn't my  logic correct?

Comment: Just do what @baao said. Will be fixed

Comment: You have essentially set cols to a number so you dont need to do if cols.length == 8 it would be if cols == 8

Comment: no because cols is an int not an object. it has no "length" property. you already retrieved the length on the line above. `if cols === 8` would be correct.

Comment: Oh okay thank you makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tried to get a length of an integer, not array. Look, `var cols = $('.col-lg-2').length`, `cols` is alreay a length. And that statement is wrong `if(cols.length == 8)`. Write simply `if(cols == 8)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the first line you are assigning the length to the variable `cols`, so its value is `8`. I think you were expecting to be an array so you'd call `cols.length` on the second line.

You can either assign the whole array to `cols`, so the first line will be:

```
cols = $('.col-lg-2');
if(cols.length === 8) {
   ...
```

or you can change only the second line to:

```
if(cols === 8) {
  ...
```

Because in the first line you are saying that the value of `cols` is `8` and then on the second line you're calling `8.length` which doesn't return what you expect.